# Enable SSH two factor authentication but only for root user

Tags: ssh, google-authenticator

I would like to enable 2 factor auth using google-authenticator when I SSH as root. Is it possible to set it up only for root but not for other non- root users? Or is it once setup, all users must have 2 factor. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you have 2 factor setup for SSH on Ubuntu it will be required for all users who are using "password authentication", but as Key-Based Authentication takes priority (happens before password authentication) you can set that up for users who you do not want 2 factor for.

Then you can go ahead and simply specified that key-based authetication only be disabled for all users with the following in the sshd_config file:

```
PubkeyAuthentication no
```

And only enabled for specific users via

```
Match User <username>
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

As an added security tip you can allow only spesific users with

```
AllowUsers <username> <username2>
```